# Assert date validation error [symfony]

Tags: php, symfony

When I'm trying validate $date with assert, like this :
@Assert\Date()

```
 /**
 * @ORM\Column(type="date")
 * @DatagridColumn(sortable=TRUE)
 * @Assert\Date()
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 */
private $date;
```

But I have an error :

> Error: Call to a member function format() on string
>
> 500 Internal Server Error - FatalErrorException

Does anyone know, why it's happening ?

> From documentation: TYPE could be string.

I also checked the format using dump() and it's correct > YYYY-MM-DD

Without validation it works correct.

Thank you for any information

Comment: Where's the code that's causing the problem? Can you edit your post and post that particular code please?

Answer (score 0):

You have this error because the property `$date` is a string, but should be an object `DateTime`.